# How to set a new position/radio for a circle with openlayers?

Tags: openlayers-3

In [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/ob7ggtx6/64/) or in [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ob7ggtx6/24/), how can I move the circle to a new position and change the radio on fly?

I tried, but it is not working:

```
circle.setPosition(ol.proj.transform([GPS_lon, GPS_lat], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'));
```

PS: I'm not even sure if I can create a circle in an easiest way :$

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ol.geom.Circle](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.geom.Circle.html) has two methods that you can use for this: [setCenter(center)](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.geom.Circle.html#setCenter) and [setCenterAndRadius(center, radius, opt_layout)](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.geom.Circle.html#setCenterAndRadius).

```
circle.setCenterAndRadius(
    ol.proj.transform([4.1833, 46.3833], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
    500000
);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ob7ggtx6/72/